# Remove duplicates keeping entry with largest absolute value

Tags: r, duplicates

Let's say I have four samples: id=1, 2, 3, and 4, with one or more measurements on each of those samples:

```
> a <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4), value=c(1,2,3,-4,-5,6))
> a
  id value
1  1     1
2  1     2
3  2     3
4  2    -4
5  3    -5
6  4     6
```

I want to remove duplicates, keeping only one entry per ID - the one having the largest absolute value of the "value" column. I.e., this is what I want:

```
> a[c(2,4,5,6), ]
  id value
2  1     2
4  2    -4
5  3    -5
6  4     6
```

How might I do this in R?

Comment: You mention "*keeping only one entry per ID - the one having the largest absolute value of the 'value' column.*" What is the desired behavior if more than one entry per ID matches that condition? Return both values, or either one? For example, what's your desired output if `a[3, 2] <- 4`?

Comment: Ah.. that's a good question. The value column is a actually real number not an integer, and will very likely never be exactly equal. Ideal desired behavior should probably be to discard both observations, but this probably won't happen as I said.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First. Sort in the order putting the less desired items last within `id` groups

```
 aa <- a[order(a$id, -abs(a$value) ), ] #sort by id and reverse of abs(value)
```

Then: Remove items after the first within `id` groups

```
aa[ !duplicated(aa$id), ] #logical index extracts only first row within each id
  id value
2  1     2
4  2    -4
5  3    -5
6  4     6
```

This could keep the minimum if the sort were not reversed.

Answer (score 15):

A `data.table` approach might be in order if your data set is very large:

```
library(data.table)

aDT <- as.data.table(a)
setkey(aDT,"id")

aDT[J(unique(id)), list(value = value[which.max(abs(value))])]
```

Or a not as fast, but still fast, alternative :

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(a)[, .SD[which.max(abs(value))], by=id]
```

This version returns all the columns of `a`, in case there are more in the real dataset.

Comment: It's not working for me, all I get is one value, in a one row one column DT. Has the syntax changed? The second example works instead.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
        group_by(id) %>%
        top_n(1, abs(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
#     id value
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2
#2     2    -4
#3     3    -5
#4     4     6
```

Comment: Just in case someone else needs to use -1 to get the min instead.  `top_n(-1, abs(value))`

Comment: It's handy, but could someone explain me the logic of this?

Comment: @Negrito `top_n()` is wrapper to select the top or bottom entries per group. More details [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html). Here, we are interested in the largest (`top_n(n = 1,...)`) absolute value for the "value" column `top_n(..., wt = abs(value))`

Answer (score 10):

Check out `?aggregate`:

```
aggregate(value~id,a,function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])
```

---

I like the answer by @DWin, but I would like show how this could also work with metadata:

```
aa<-merge(aggregate(value~id,a,function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))]),a)
# Fails if the max value is duplicated for a single id without next line.
aa[!duplicated(aa),]
```

---

I couldn't help myself and created one last answer:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(a,a$id),function(x) x[which.max(abs(x$value)),]))
```

Comment: This works well as per my description, but I should have been more informative. There is actually a single ID and many other metadata columns that are the same for each ID, and many other value columns for each ID. I want to keep all of the columns in the data frame, not just the one id and value.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach (though the code might look a little cumbersome) is to use `ave()`:

```
a[which(abs(a$value) == ave(a$value, a$id, 
                            FUN=function(x) max(abs(x)))), ]
#   id value
# 2  1     2
# 4  2    -4
# 5  3    -5
# 6  4     6
```

Comment: @DWin, ["I learned it by watching you!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-Elr5K2Vuo). ;)

Comment: Heh. Not from my cultural framework, but the Scrubs outtakes I got to after the "brain on drugs" clip at youtube were curiously amusing.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(a, .(id), function(x) return(x[which(abs(x$value)==max(abs(x$value))),]))
```

Comment: plyr is terribly slow

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with dplyr as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(n == max(n)) %>%
  ungroup()
```