# Filter dataframe by maximum values in each group

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have a 180,000 x 400 dataframe where the rows correspond to users but every user has exactly two rows.

```
id   date  ...
1    2012    ...
3    2010    ...
2    2013    ...
2    2014    ...
1    2011    ...
3    2014    ...
```

I want to subset the data so that only the most recent row for each user is retained (i.e. the row with the highest value for date for each id).

I first tried using `which()` looping `ids` with an `ifelse()` statement in `sapply()` which was painfully slow (`O(n^2)` I believe).

Then I tried sorting the `df` by `id` and then looping through in increments of two and comparing adjacent dates but this was also slow (I guess because loops in R are hopeless). The comparison of the two dates is the bottleneck as the sort was pretty much instant.

Is there a way to vectorize the comparison?

SOLUTION from [Remove duplicates keeping entry with largest absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12805964/4346952)

```
aa <- df[order(df$id, -df$date), ] #sort by id and reverse of date
aa[!duplicated(aa$id),]
```

Runs very quickly!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's a simple and fast approach using data.table package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(date)], id]
#    id date
# 1:  1 2012
# 2:  3 2014
# 3:  2 2014
```

Or (could be a bit faster because of *keyed* `by`

```
setkey(setDT(df), id)[, .SD[which.max(date)], id]
```

Or using OPs idea via the `data.table` package

```
unique(setorder(setDT(df), id, -date), by = "id")
```

Or

```
setorder(setDT(df), id, -date)[!duplicated(id)]
```

Or base R solution

```
with(df, tapply(date, id, function(x) x[which.max(x)]))
##    1    2    3 
## 2012 2014 2014
```

Another way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(date == max(date)) # Will keep all existing columns but allow multiple rows in case of ties
# Source: local data table [3 x 2]
# Groups: id
# 
#   id date
# 1  1 2012
# 2  2 2014
# 3  3 2014
```

Or

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(which.max(date)) # Will keep all columns but won't return multiple rows in case of ties
```

Or

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(max(date)) # Will remove all other columns and wont return multiple rows in case of ties
```

Comment: The dplyr options in your answer produce the same output for the small sample data, but for other data each may behave different: `filter` will keep all existing columns but allow multiple rows in case of ties; `slice` will keep all columns but won't return multiple rows in case of ties; and `summarise` will remove all other columns and wont return multiple rows in case of ties. Just as an info for people who see this later on ..

Comment: @docendodiscimus These are great observations. You are free to add these explanations to my solution as my `dplyr` guru

Comment: Well, I added them already in the comments, so not necessary to put it in the answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

aggregate should also work:

```
aggregate(date ~ id, df, max)
```

Comment: Would be very very slow though for a big data set...

Comment: actually it takes 1.5 seconds on my crummy laptop @DavidArenburg. Your base solution takes < 1 sec, so cheers to you

Comment: @rawr for what data size?

Comment: `dat           data.frame 578922376  552.1 Mb 180000  402`