# Select highest values in a dataframe by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following `df`

```
dat <- data.frame(Cases = c("Student3","Student3","Student3","Student1","Student1",
"Student2","Student2","Student2","Student4"), Class = rep("Math", 9),
Scores = c(9,5,2,7,3,8,5,1,7), stringsAsFactors = F)


> dat
   Cases    Class   Scores
1 Student3  Math      9
2 Student3  Math      5
3 Student3  Math      2
4 Student1  Math      7
5 Student1  Math      3
6 Student2  Math      8
7 Student2  Math      5
8 Student2  Math      1
9 Student4  Math      7
```

On the other hand, I have another df with the following information:

```
d <- data.frame(Cases = c("Student3", "Student1",
"Student2", "Student4"), Class = rep("Math", 4), stringsAsFactors = F)

    Cases  Class
1 Student3  Math
2 Student1  Math
3 Student2  Math
4 Student4  Math
```

With these two, I want to extract the highest `scores` for each `student`. So my output would look like this:

```
> dat_output
    Cases  Class   Scores
1 Student3  Math      9
2 Student1  Math      7
3 Student2  Math      8
4 Student4  Math      7
```

I tried with `merge` but it is not extracting just the highest `scores`.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because I never asked to use a library. Plus, the accepted answer was written on `base R`, not on `dplyr`.

Comment: possible duplicate then of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534284/filter-dataframe-by-maximum-values-in-each-group/27534390

Comment: @Tjebo Yes, there are many other posts with "find max per group", but this post has "filter" step: only do this for subset of students that are also in d dataframe.

Comment: @Tjebo please read the question carefully, it doesn't ask for maximum in group.

Comment: @RonakShah the title speaks a different language to me.

Comment: @zx8754 Even if the list of groups that the maximum is to be found for come from a different dataframe, it's still a "maximum in group" question that has numerous duplicates (8+ just searching with the current title). The "filter" step is not reflected in the question title, and to be honest should be a separate question anyway (which also [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612235/select-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-values-in-a-vector)).

Comment: @MikkoMarttila do (vote) as you wish, of course. Agree to disagree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `sapply` on each `Cases` in `d`, subset the `dat` for that `Cases` and get the `max` score for it.

```
sapply(d$Cases, function(x) max(dat$Scores[dat$Cases %in% x]))

#Student3 Student1 Student2 Student4 
#       9        7        8        7
```

To get the result as data.frame

```
transform(d, Scores = sapply(d$Cases, function(x) 
                     max(dat$Scores[dat$Cases %in% x])))

#    Cases Class Scores
# Student3  Math      9 
# Student1  Math      7
# Student2  Math      8
# Student4  Math      7
```

Note - I have assumed your `d` to be

```
d <- data.frame(Cases = c("Student3", "Student1",
      "Student2", "Student4"), Class = rep("Math", 4), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: also `tapply()` can do it

Comment: In this case, how can I convert the result to `df`?

Comment: With the updated answer, I just get the `scores` without `student#`... do you get `students` and `scores`?

Comment: @Cahidora Those were row names actually, added an option with `transform` instead, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Simple, fast and no libraries needed... Works great! Thanks.

Comment: One last thing... in case I have an extra column right next to `Class` in `dat` and I want to include it in the output, where can I add it?

Comment: @Cahidora On what basis do you want to select the value in additional column? Would it be corresponding value of `max` ?

Comment: It is just a column with extra info corresponding to the `max` value.

Comment: @Cahidora Sorry, my mind is bit blocked right now, I could not come up with anything better than `cbind(d, t(sapply(d$Cases, function(x) {
  sub_df = dat[dat$Cases %in% x,];
  inds = which.max(sub_df$Scores);
  c(sub_df$Scores[inds], sub_df$New[inds])
})))` at the moment where `New` is the additional column you want to add.

Comment: @RonakShah works great to add the columns... you're a genius! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If I am correct you don't need `d`, since in `d` there is no additional information that is not in `dat` already.

You can just do:

```
dat_output <- aggregate(Scores ~ Cases, dat, max)
dat_output

     Cases Scores
1 Student1      7
2 Student2      8
3 Student3      9
4 Student4      7
```

Comment: There might be certain entries in `d` which are not present in `dat`. Not necessary the sample represents the actual data.

Answer (score 3):

with `dplyr`, and considering the case where your `d` contains a subset of students from your `dat`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(d, dat %>% group_by(Cases, Class) %>% summarize(Scores=max(Scores)))

# Cases Class Scores
#1 Student3  Math      9
#2 Student1  Math      7
#3 Student2  Math      8
#4 Student4  Math      7
```

if order does not matter then the following is more efficient:

```
inner_join(dat, d) %>% group_by(Cases, Class) %>% summarize(Scores=max(Scores))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Cases [?]
#  Cases    Class Scores
#  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
#1 Student1 Math       7
#2 Student2 Math       8
#3 Student3 Math       9
#4 Student4 Math       7
```

Comment: This is the answer I prefer. I suggest do the join first then pipe the merged data to group_by, etc.

Comment: Yes but that will change the order of the elements in your final output (order will be different from `d`), although it will be efficient in terms of query optimization etc.

Comment: Good point, I prefer efficiency over how the data is ordered.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sqldf` package as follow:

```
sqldf("select max(Scores), Cases from dat JOIN d USING(Cases) group by Cases")
```

Apply `JOIN` operation, `group by cases` and `select max(Scores),Cases` to get the desired output:

```
   max(Scores)    Cases
1           7    Student1
2           8    Student2
3           9    Student3
4           7    Student4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort your dataframe on `Scores` in descending order using `order`. Then remove duplicate `Cases`. This is a `base` R solution.

```
dat <- dat[order(-dat$Scores),]
dat[duplicated(dat$Cases)==F,]

     Cases Class Scores
1 Student3  Math      9
6 Student2  Math      8
4 Student1  Math      7
9 Student4  Math      7
```

If you first want to make sure that all samples in `dat` are also in `d`, you can, in a first step, do this. `%in%` performs value matching. It, however, does not make a difference based on the example above.

```
dat <- dat[dat$Cases %in% d$Cases & dat$Class %in% d$Class,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Cases, Class) %>% 
  summarise(Scores = max(Scores))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Cases [?]
  Cases    Class Scores
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 Student1 Math      7.
2 Student2 Math      8.
3 Student3 Math      9.
4 Student4 Math      7.
```

Considering you want to match the two dfs:

```
df %>%  
  right_join(df2, by = c("Cases", "Class")) %>% 
  group_by(Cases, Class) %>% 
  summarise(Scores = max(Scores))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Cases [?]
  Cases    Class Scores
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 Student1 Math      7.
2 Student2 Math      8.
3 Student3 Math      9.
4 Student4 Math      7.
```

Comment: you need to group by with class too, in case there are multiple class values

Comment: After edits, now this looks like copy of @SandipanDey 's answer.

Comment: I think it is obvious that we are using (slightly) different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Using *dplyr*, group by students, and get first value based on scores:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  filter(Cases %in% d$Cases) %>% 
  group_by(Cases) %>% 
  top_n(1, Scores) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Cases    Class Scores
#   <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Student1 Math       7
# 2 Student2 Math       8
# 3 Student3 Math       9
# 4 Student4 Math       7
```